# Why doesn't this br tag do anything

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP loop listing results from a database:

What I have done is write an if statement in PHP so that every time 4 results have been outputted, execute a line of code.  I then put a break tag inside this loop so that every 4 results, there would be a break `<br />` tag. It looks like this:

```
if ($i %4 == 0){
    echo "<br />";
    echo $i;
}
```

When I look at the source code of the site the `<br />` tag is there, but it doesn't move the rest of the information to another line. When I add a different line of code it shows, for example, if I print `<p>Hello</p>`, it outputs 'Hello'.

It just seems to be the `<br />` that doesn't work. This results in all the results after the first 4 being off the end of the screen.

Here is the whole page and a screenshot of the output:

```
<section class="hero is-dark is-halfheight is-bold">
<div class="hero-head">
</div>
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="columns">
      <?php
              $i = 0;   
              foreach($_SESSION['all'] as $result) {
              echo '<div class="column is-3">';
              echo '<a href="#">';
              echo '<div class="box has-text-centered">';
              echo $result;
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</a>';

              echo '</div>';

              $i++;
              if ($i %4 == 0){
                echo "<br />";
                echo $i;
              }
          }   
      ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And...

[image: Screenshot of output in browser]

Comment: and `$_SESSION['all']` is assigned where/how exactly?

Comment: Instead of br, use a <div class="row">

Comment: yes, what does your css look like? your class says columns. I thinks thats what you are getting

Comment: BR doesn't work between DIVs...

Comment: `br` is a lousy markup solution to nearly all issues.  In this case, as @TommasoBelluzzo points out, `br` has no effect between `div` tags.  Further, your question is very misleading: This question should be "why doesn't my break tag do anything?", and the contents should include the HTML - your PHP has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: `if (($i%4) == 0)` try like this & print multiple `<br>`

Comment: Also, its not valid to have a `div` inside an `a`.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to bear with me, I'm quite new to web development. So are you guys saying I just need to find another way to add a break other than '< br />'? and if so what are some I could use. I tried '<div class="row">' but it just squashed the rest of the boxes down the right side of the screen.

Comment: if ($i %4) ... <div style="clear:left"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet is because your CSS styling overrides `br` behavior. Take a look below snippet (open in full page), multiple `br`s doesn't do anything.

I presume you're using [bulma](https://bulma.io/) CSS, and not going to talk about why does it work since there already well explained docs written.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">

<section class="hero is-dark is-halfheight is-bold">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 1 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 1 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 1 3
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 2 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 2 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-3">
          <div class="box has-text-centered">
            Box 2 3
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Instead, wrap those `column` within another `columns` container. Just like below,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">

    <section class="hero is-dark is-halfheight is-bold">
      <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container has-text-centered">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 1 1
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 1 2
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 1 3
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="columns">  
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 2 1
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 2 2
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
              <div class="box has-text-centered">
                Box 2 3
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
     
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Then so, you're PHP code would likely to be as follow,

```
<section class="hero is-dark is-halfheight is-bold">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        $nextClosingDivShouldBePrinted = [];

        foreach($_SESSION['all'] as $result) {
            if ($i % 4 == 0){
              echo '<div class="columns">';
              $nextClosingDivShouldBePrinted[] = $i + 3; // there will be 3 'column' to wrap in for modulus 4.
            }

            echo '<div class="column is-3">';
            echo '<a href="#" class="box has-text-centered">';

            echo $result;

            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>';

            if (in_array($i, $nextClosingDivShouldBePrinted)) {
                echo '</div>';
            }

            $i++; //always put loop increment at lowest part.
        }
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: this really helped! I now just don't understand why all the content has shifted over to the left of the page. It breaks after every 4 and moves to the next line, but it's all only taking up two-thirds of the page?

Comment: glad it helped. you can mark it as answer if you want. anyways, it works as intended, if you're with bulma, and as stated in [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/#12-columns-system): _how many columns you want out of 12_ , which means a total grid of 12 (which is browser width) being divided by 3 (by `is-3` class). To fill it fully, ofc, `is-4` (or even no `is-*` class at all) should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Br will not work, you will have to wrap your code in a row div like so:

```
<section class="hero is-dark is-halfheight is-bold">
<div class="hero-head">
</div>
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="columns">
      <?php
        $i = 0;   
        foreach($_SESSION['all'] as $result) {
            if ($i %4 == 0){
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo $i;
            }
            echo '<div class="column is-3">';
            echo '<a href="#">';
            echo '<div class="box has-text-centered">';
            echo $result;
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</a>';

            echo '</div>';

            $i++;
            if ($i %4 == 0){
            echo "</div>";
            echo $i;
            }
        }   
      ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<style>
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```